# Access value of a nested inline callback function in javascript

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm struggling accessing values that get returned via a nested inline callback function, from outside.

Below is a snipped of the code which I bound to. To be explicit I like to access all `bbb` results.

```
myfunction(){

    var allB = [];

    getFunctionA(para1, function (aaa, error) {
        for (var index = 0; index < aaa.length; ++index) {
            getFunctionB(para1, aaa[index].id, function (bbb, error) {
                allB = allB.concat(bbb);                    
            });
        }
    });


    //How to work with all bbb's 

}
```

Any idea how to access these values? `allB = allB.concat(bbb);` will not give me the values (`allB` is empty).

Comment: Those functions are probably **asynchronous**.

Comment: What does `getFunctionA` and `getFunctionB` do?

Comment: @evolutionxbox performing get requests from the internet

Comment: @Pointy OP has confirmed functions are asynchronous.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the possible duplicate is useful, but not answering the question/problem.